# How do you make flat shading for games?

Tags: materials, game-engine, shaders, workflow, transparency

Just wanted advice on how to make flat shaders/renders like this for game characters. Especially transparent ones like the frog's raincoat and the glass cover of the terrarium. 
 Any help would be appreciated! :) 
 first image is from https://izachudy.com/post/165380040065/this-summer-i-participated-in-a-game-jam-with and the second is from https://aveadore.tumblr.com/post/163060936668/tiny-garden-for-this-month-low-poly-challenge

[image]

[image: artist credit https://aveadore.tumblr.com/post/163060936668/tiny-garden-for-this-month-low-poly-challenge]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shaders are managed by the render engines. If you want to make assets for a video game, then the render engine is the game engine, and so the way to make shaders in it depends on him, not on Blender. The shaders will be made in your game engine and might not have an equivalent in Blender.

The only thing you can do in Blender is to prepare the textures you will use in your shaders, as well as assign materials slots on your mesh if you need several materials on a single mesh.

Comment: i see! thank you so much :) would you know how to go about making a semi-transparent texture like the frog's coat?

Comment: That would be in the shaders settings, in your game engine. Not in Blender. Usually it's a simple value between 0 and 1, and some engines might allow you to alternatively use a black and white map if you want variations of transparency inside the material.

Comment: hmm ok :) but how about making it in blender to achieve toon water or toon glass?

Comment: @misosoups Hello :). Please mark the answer as accepted **✓**, if it helped. If you have other questions, please post them as new, separate questions.

Comment: @misosoups use the alpha input on a principled node. I recommend you also watch this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cvu5XYrZT6Q